# Weird precision issues with currency field

Tags: visualforce

I have a currency field that is defined as 16,2 for the length and decimal places. On my VF page, I refer to the field below, and I get 4 decimal places. Why does that happen, and how do I resolve this?

Thanks!

```
                     <apex:column >
                      <apex:facet name="header"> 
                      {!$ObjectType.myobj__c.fields.myfield__c.Label}
                      </apex:facet>
                     {!f.myfield__c}
                    </apex:column>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database will hold more than the precision and scale defined on the field. If it was entered with 4 decimals the database stores 4 decimals

Using the apex:outputfield instead of simply if displaying the merge variable will get you the formatting defined for the field.

You could also use java message format like so

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,number,###,###.00}">
      <apex:param value="{!youfield}"/>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: oh, i didn't know that the field would store additional precision.  I can't use apex:output field, because i'm running into state issues on the page.

Comment: Then fix the state issues or use java messaging to format the output